# WPDB Wordpress Strip Slashes (Remove Slashes)

Tags: wordpress

I use WPDB Class in Wordpress for my Data within my theme...

Now lets say in the database we have saved

```
This isn\'t my name
```

Now, I want to remove the slash for the complete fields using the following method

```
  $query= 'SELECT * FROM quotes'; 
  $quotes= $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Is there a way how I can do something **recursive** for all fields in $quotes that will practically to stripslashes (PHP) and return me something like (for all fields within the object)

```
This isn't my name
```

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is [stripslashes_deep](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep).

Answer (score 1):

Since the `$wpdb->get_results()` funciton returns an array of `stdClass` objects, in order to remove the slashes in all columns in every row, you must iterate through the rows, and through the properties of each row object running the PHP `stripslashes()` function on it.

```
foreach( $quotes as &$quote ) {
    foreach( $quote as &$field ) {
        if ( is_string( $field ) )
            $field = stripslashes( $field );
    }
}
```

More information on the wpdb->get_results() function:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results